# Where to download cryptsetup-luks-devel package?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, cryptsetup, dm-crypt

How to download and install cryptsetup-luks-devel package for Debian? I can't find it. When I google I get this package only for CentOS.

Comment: The very suffix `*-devel` is RHEL/CentOS/Fedora-style. Debian uses `*-dev` or `lib*-dev` instead. What is the problem you're trying to solve by finding such a package for Debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On debian ,the package is called [`libcryptsetup-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libcryptsetup-dev):

> This package provides the libcryptsetup development files.

```
sudo apt install libcryptsetup-dev
```